# Filtering matching patterns with regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl, filter

I'm not very familiar with regular expressions in perl.
I want to filter names from a string e.g. "`child mick jagger child john wayne child archimedes`" between tags "`child`".

Result should be:

```
mick jagger

john wayne

archimedes
```

The number of names in the string is variable.

My perl program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict 'vars';
use strict 'subs';
my ($x);
my $s="child mick jagger child john wayne child archimedes";

my @f=$s=~/(child.+(?!child))/igs;
foreach $x (@f)
{
    print "$x\n";
};
```

The program didn't work. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

You might use:

```
\bchild \K(?:(?!child).)*(?!\S)
```

- `\bchild`  Match child preceded with a word boundary and followed by a space
- `\K` Forget what was matched
- `(?:(?!child).)*` Match any char except a newline not followed by child
- `(?!\S)` Assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZFi3L/1)

Or use a non greedy dot variant

```
\bchild \K.+?(?= child|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tszc3V/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with *lookbehind*:

```
?<=\bchild )(?:(?! child).)+
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8WG1XP/2/)

```
use strict;

my $s="child mick jagger child john wayne child archimedes";
my @f = $s =~/(?<=\bchild )(?:(?! child).)+/ig;
foreach my $x (@f) {
    print "$x\n";
};
```

Prints:

```
mick jagger
john wayne
archimedes
```